# Delete the footer only on the last page using CSS

Tags: html, css, pdf, dompdf

I'm working on generate pdf. I want to remove the last page using css method, i'm trying to get `:last-child` for remove it but the results is nothing.

My code:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.85em;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  line-height: 0.95em;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -30px;
  right: 0px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 270px;
  text-align: left;
}

footer .page-number:after {
  content: counter(page);
}

footer .page-number .last:last-child {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<body>

  <footer>

    <div class="right" style="margin-left: -85px;">
      <span class="page-number"></span>
    </div>

    <table width="100%" class="last">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span style="
        border: 1px solid;
        box-sizing: border-box;padding-right: 0.88cm;padding-left: 5px;vertical-align: middle;">Roles I &nbsp;</span>
          <span style="width: 300px;
        border-top: 1px solid;
        border-right: 1px solid;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
        margin-left: -6px;
        box-sizing: border-box;padding-right: 70px;vertical-align: middle;">&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;</span><br>

          <span style="
        border-left: 1px solid;
        border-right: 1px solid;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
        box-sizing: border-box;padding-right: 1.32cm;padding-left: 5px;vertical-align: middle;">Roles II</span>
          <span style="width: 300px;
        border-right: 1px solid;
        border-bottom: 1px solid;
        margin-left: -6px;
        box-sizing: border-box;padding-right: 70px;vertical-align: middle; ">&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;&ensp;</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </footer>
  MY content here until N - Page and i want to remove the last footer
</body>
```

as you can see in the example in this picture, I have a number of 3 pages and in the footer there are numbers and boxes that I have marked red. I just want to delete the data in the red box, but for the page number section I don't want to delete it.
[image]

Note : I'm using dompdf library

Comment: `.last` is not a child of `.page-number`. In fact, they're not even siblings. Your selector doesn't make sense. Perhaps you're looking for `footer:last-of-type .page-number, footer:last-of-type .last`

Comment: I'm just following this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_last-child

Comment: `:last-child` targets the last child element that matches the given selector before the pseudo element. However, your selector will not match anything. The problem is not the `:last-child`, it's the selector before it.

Comment: I'm following your code using this `footer:last-of-type .page-number, footer:last-of-type .last { display: none; }` all of my footer is gone, using this `footer:last-of-type .page-number {display: none}` all of my page number is gone,  and using this `footer:last-of-type .last { display: none; }` all of my red boxes is gone

Comment: Your footers must not be siblings. Pseudos are relative to the immediate parent, so you have to target the elements which are siblings. I made a full answer for more explanation.

Comment: Beyond the CSS selector issues ... this isn't really something you can do only through CSS with Dompdf. You would need to use the canvas class directly with a combination of embedded script to capture the footer and page script determine whether or not to render it.

Comment: Any solution? i also want to remove the running header from last page of pdf

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is your selector, which does not target anything.

This selector: `footer .page-number .last:last-child` is targeting the last child element with className `last` of an element with className `page-number` inside a footer element.

This would look something like this:

```
<footer>
    <div class="page-number">
        <div class="last"></div>
        <div class="last"></div> <!-- It would target this element -->
    </div>
</footer>
```

However, your structure looks like this:

```
<footer>
    <div class="right">
        <span class="page-number"></span>
    </div>
    <table class="last"></table>
<footer>
```

It seems like you are trying to target *both* `.page-number` and `.last` in the last footer element in the page, which can be done using a different pseudo-selector, `:last-of-type`.

The selector would look like this:

```
footer:last-of-type .page-number,
footer:last-of-type .last
```

This targets all elements with className `page-number` or `last` inside the last `<footer>` element on the page.

This of course assumes that your footers are all siblings. If they are not, then you have to move the `:last-of-type` or `:last-child` up the tree until you are on the elements which are siblings.

For instance, in this case:

```
<div><footer></footer></div>
<div><footer></footer></div>
<div><footer></footer></div>
```

You would want to match the div, rather than the footer, since pseudo-elements are relative to their parent, and each footer is the only footer inside its parent.

Comment: I want to make the footer dynamic, so I set my footer position `fixed`. and I don't know how many pages I have,  so I only call the footer once.