# Unable To Remove header from First page?

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to remove the header from only the first page while printing,
or Saving it to PDF
but it's not working
I have tried the below CSS codes but none of theme are working:
I have also visited these link but but none of the answer worked for me
[Remove Header from First Page of HTML Generated PDF - CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30500871/remove-header-from-first-page-of-html-generated-pdf-css)
and [Delete the footer only on the last page using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56244878/delete-the-footer-only-on-the-last-page-using-css)

```
@page: first {
  @top-left {
          content: normal;
          }
       }
   @page :not(:first) {
}
```

Both of theme didn't worked.

my styles

```
    <style type="text/css">
      .page-header,
      .page-header-space {
        height: 100px;
      }

      .page-footer,
      .page-footer-space {
        height: 50px;

      }

      .page-footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;

        border-top: 1px solid black;
        /* for demo */
        background: white;
       
      }

      .page-header {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0mm;
        width: 100%;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        /* for demo */
        background: white;
        /* for demo */
      }

      .page {
        page-break-after: always;
      }

      @page {
        margin: 10mm;
      }

      @media print {
        thead {
          display: table-header-group;
        }

        tfoot {
          display: table-footer-group;
        }

        button {
          display: none;
        }

        body {
          margin: 0;
        }

        @page: first {
          @top-left {
            content: normal;
          }
        }

        .main_paragraph {
          white-space: pre-line;
          white-space: pre-wrap;
          line-height: 25px;
          font-size: 16px;
          margin-right: 10px;
          margin-left: 10px;
          text-indent: 30px;
          text-align: justify
        }
    </style>
```

my Body

```
  <body>
    <div class="page-header" style="text-align: center">
    </div>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <!--place holder for the fixed-position header-->
            <div class="page-header-space"></div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <!--*** CONTENT GOES HERE ***-->
            <div>
              <img src="{{URL::asset("img/logo.jpg")}}" style="width: 90%;display: block;margin: 0 auto;z-index: 1;">
            </div>
            <table id="main_table" dir="rtl"
              style="width: 95%;text-align:center; margin: 0 auto;border-collapse: collapse;" border="1">
              <tbody>
                <tr style="font-size: 18px;font-weight:bold;height:40px">
                  <td style="width: 47.5%">sugestion</td>
                  <td style="width: 7%">date</td>
                  <td style="width: 46.5%">order</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td style="border-bottom: hidden;text-align:right">
                    <p style="text-align: right;font-size: 19px;margin-right:30px;font-weight:bold">
                      {{$result[0]->name}}</p>
                  </td>
                  <td rowspan="2"></td>
                  <td rowspan="2"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  {{-- <td>{{strlen($result[0]->document_text)}}
          </td> --}}
          @if(strlen($result[0]->document_text)<=977) <td style="vertical-align: top;border-top:hidden;height:65vh"
            dir="rtl">
            @else
            <td style="vertical-align: top;border-top:hidden;" dir="rtl">
              @endif
              {{$result[0]->document_text}}
              <p class="main_paragraph" dir="rtl" lang="ar">{{$result[0]->document_text}}</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <!--place holder for the fixed-position footer-->
          <div class="page-footer-space"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>

    </table>
    <div class="page-footer" style="text-align: center;width:94.5%;margin-left:2.55%">
    </div>

  </body>
```

I'm testing it on chrome.

[image]

Comment: Which "header" are you trying to hide when printed? The header and footer added by the browser or the section of your page marked with `class="page-header"`

Comment: the section of page which is marked with  class="page-header"

Comment: Have you tried adding `.page-header { display: none; }` to the `@media print { ...` section of your css? I can't see anything in your code which would stop the header from being shown, no matter the medium.

Comment: yes but didn't worked

Answer (score 1):

You can use media query in CSS to fix that

media query is used to hide an element when printing web pages. Use @media print query and set the display none or visibility hidden to that element that needs to hide at printing

**like this**

```
@media print{
   .page-header{
       display:none;
   }
}
```

if this doesn't work with you try to add `media = print` link on an HTML page

like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

If still doesn't work try to add CSS code to the HTML page

Like This

```
<style>
 @media print{
       .page-header{
           display:none;
       }
    }
</style>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but It will remove the header from all pages but I only want to remove it from first page

Comment: I have edited the answer 
please try the last one
and tell me what happen

Comment: same think it remove header from all pages

Comment: check the last one :D

I want to help you  :)

Answer (score 1):

**try to do it with Laravel**

```
<div class="header 
@if(Route::currentRouteName() === 'yourPage')
    {{hied-in-print}}
@endif "></div>
```

and use this class hied-in-print in `@media print`

```
<style>
 
    @media print{
           .hied-in-print{
               display:none;
           }
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: thanks for your help I have updated my post please check the photo i have uploaded

Comment: the css you wrote works for all pages in print but i only want to remove the first page header

Answer (score 0):

It seems you must provide blank content to remove the header:

```
@page {
  @top-center {
    content: "HEADER";
  }
}
@page :first {
  @top-center {
    content: "";
  }
}
```